# Why was this question closed for being too localized?

Tags: support

In the link below I'm asking a question about language based subfolders and their affect on language in Google search results.

My question can be applied to all sites adding translations to their sites not just Japanese to English and vice versa which is what I'm using as an example.

[Multilingual sites and Google search results, do subfolders really work?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/36304/multilingual-sites-and-google-search-results-do-subfolders-really-work)

Edit: I'm assuming the question was closed because I specifically referenced a domain of mine for context; although I feel the question itself is still generally relevant even with the domain, as I can find no specific information regarding subfolders affecting search results, I have removed it from the question.

Comment: I can't answer your question but this may be relevant info for you: [SEO consequences for merging country sites in a .com](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8384)

Comment: Nothing at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question was asking if YOU were being impatient or were doing something wrong in how you were adding multi-language support for your website. If you had phrased it thus:

"What are the best practices for ensuring that the correct langauge version of my website is displayed through Google and other search engines? And how long will it take before the new language version becomes prominent in search engine results?"

And used your specific case as an example, then it would pertain to any website owner looking to expand into new languages.

Perhaps the  person that closed the question should have tried to help you rephrase the question first, but your question as it stands is not particularly useful for other users.

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: I'll accept this as it's at least an answer.  If this is truly the reason then I'm a bit disappointed that the person that closed the question doesn't think people can't extrapolate information from questions with ME or WE in them.

Comment: @AWinter I agree, they should have worked with you to rephrase the question. Still, for future reference, it's best to start with the general and then move to the specifics. So start off with the question in my answer and then go on to explain your specific problem as an example.